# Is there a way to run opengl command on a thread other than gtk's ui thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, gtk3

I am working on an project that requires the pipeline creation and render calls to gtk's glarea be made from another thread.

I am using epoxy as the gl loader. I am also using mingw's gtk+ build on a windows system. Using a sample triangle code, creating the pipeline and rendering using glarea's `realize` and `render` signals works. But any gl call on another thread would cause the app to crash.

Here is the rendering and thread logic. I still configure the pipeline using the `realize` signal, but the rendering is done on a different thread.

window class

```cpp
#include "window.h"
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

namespace M
{

Window::Window()
{
    set_border_width(6);
    set_default_size(640, 480);

    _box.set_spacing(6);
    add(_box);

    _box.pack_end(ngl, Gtk::PACK_EXPAND_WIDGET); // ngl : the GLArea variable

    show_all();

    thread = std::thread( [this] { render(); } );
}

void Window::render()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);

    ngl.renderTri();
}

}
```

GLArea class

```cpp
#include "glarea.h"

namespace M
{

GLArea::GLArea()
    : _points(0),
      _colors(0),
      _matrix(0),
      _isButton3Pressed(false),
      _isKeyWPressed(false),
      _isKeyAPressed(false),
      _isKeySPressed(false),
      _isKeyDPressed(false)
{
    set_has_window(false);

    // It is important to explicitely allow events on the GLArea!
    _glArea.add_events(Gdk::POINTER_MOTION_MASK
            | Gdk::BUTTON_PRESS_MASK
            | Gdk::BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK
            | Gdk::KEY_PRESS_MASK
            | Gdk::KEY_RELEASE_MASK);

    pack_end(_glArea, Gtk::PACK_EXPAND_WIDGET);

    _glArea.signal_realize().connect(
            sigc::mem_fun(*this, &GLArea::realize));
    // It is important that the unrealize signal calls our handler to clean up
    // GL resources *before* the default unrealize handler is called, hence the
    // "false".
    _glArea.signal_unrealize().connect(
            sigc::mem_fun(*this, &GLArea::unrealize), false);
    /*_glArea.signal_render().connect(
            sigc::mem_fun(*this, &GLArea::render));*/

    _glArea.signal_key_press_event().connect(
            sigc::mem_fun(*this, &GLArea::on_key_press_event), false);
    _glArea.signal_key_release_event().connect(
            sigc::mem_fun(*this, &GLArea::on_key_release_event), false);

    // Grab the focus to get all key events no matter what!
    _glArea.set_can_focus(true);
    _glArea.grab_focus();

    show_all();
}

GLArea::~GLArea()
{
}

void GLArea::renderTri()
{
    while(true)
    {
        GLArea::render();
        _glArea.queue_draw();
    }
}

bool GLArea::render()
{
    try {

    _glArea.make_current();
        _glArea.throw_if_error();

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //draw();
        if(_isKeyWPressed) {
            _matrix[13] += 0.01;
        }
        if(_isKeyAPressed) {
            _matrix[12] -= 0.01;
        }
        if(_isKeySPressed) {
            _matrix[13] -= 0.01;
        }
        if(_isKeyDPressed) {
            _matrix[12] += 0.01;
        }

        glUniformMatrix4fv(_matrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, _matrix);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        return true;
    } catch(const Gdk::GLError &error) {
        std::cerr
            << error_string()
            << "Something went wrong in the render callback\n\t"
            << "\n\tDomain: " << error.domain()
            << "\n\tCode: " << error.code()
            << "\n\tWhat: " << error.what()
            << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

full original sample can be found here. https://github.com/mschwan/glarea-animation

I expect  triangle to be show, or if there be any gl errors or warnings, it be printed, but I get a segmentation fault.
[Info] Realizing GL context
        Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400
        3.2.0 - Build 20.19.15.4963
Segmentation fault

Comment: Unfortunately - no, OpenGL context is not thread safe as well as can be used only with thread which created it.

Comment: @VictorGubin: That's not exactly true. Yes, Opengl is single-threaded and not thread-safe. There exists a 1-1 connection between thread and gl context. But you can reassign the context to any another thread (`wglMakeCurrent` on windows). As long as you make sure that everything is properly synchronized, it should be possible to render from a different thread.

Comment: @BDL comment is what I expect to happen. I have also used multiple threads rendering with opentk, each time assigning the context to the current thread by calling `MakeCurrent()`exposed by the renderer. just not with gtk